# Can I whitelist a domain for unencrypted traffic from a page served over HTTPS?

Tags: http, google-chrome, https, cross-domain

I've got an internal web application that's designed to work in concert with a server running locally on the client machine. (For the curious: the local server is used to decrypt data retrieved from the server using the client machine's GPG key.)

The internal web app is served over HTTPS while the local app is accessible via localhost. It used to be that I could make unencrypted AJAX requests from the page to localhost without any issues; but it seems that recently Chrome was updated to disallow HTTP requests to any destination from pages served over HTTPS.

I understand that in the vast majority of cases, HTTP requests from a page served via HTTPS constitute a security hole. However, since I have complete control over the endpoint in this case (i.e., localhost), it seems to me that it should still be perfectly safe to make HTTP requests to that one destination even when the host page has been served via HTTPS.

Is this possible? To whitelist localhost somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in control of both the client and the server, it sounds like a good candidate for [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (CORS). The server will have to set a few response headers to give access to the client. You can learn more here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/